# Is it possible to resend e-mails from temptables?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I have identified a large amount of e-mails stuck in the temptables of a exchange 2003 install. I know that the normal practice is to apply the correct hotfix, delete the temptables, restart and have the exchange subsystem recreate the temptables. However there are heaps of required e-mails that need to go to the intended persons.

Other than exporting the messages out of the temptables and then manually sending them off, is there anyway to "re-send" them from the temptables?

Comment: edited my question below.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the slightly infamous "blackhole" Exchange 2003 bug that would blackhole emails that failed a graylist filter (or if anti-virus fudged with Exchange) in the temp tables.

I was able to resend them by restarting the SMTP service; not sure if that'll work for you, but an easy thing to try if you haven't already done so.

EDIT

I lied; I dig some Googling around and I'm pretty sure I put the following in a batch file and ran it as a scheduled task nightly (until we switched smarthosts upstream and didn't have this issue again):

```
REM Stop services 

net stop "World Wide Web Publishing Service" 
net stop "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)" 
net stop "Microsoft Exchange Routing Engine" 
net stop "HTTP SSL" 
net stop "IIS Admin Service" 


REM Start services 

net start "IIS Admin Service" 
net start "HTTP SSL" 
net start "Microsoft Exchange Routing Engine" 
net start "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)" 
net start "World Wide Web Publishing Service"
```

Comment: Good suggestion gravyface, but I've tried restarting the SMTP service at least a dozen times now :)